# How to execute a jar file on jboss7 startup?

Tags: module, jboss7.x

I have a simple java class which displays "waiting" text on execution , in "TMSCore" java project.

```
 package com.stock.bo;

    public class example {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
             System.out.println("================================> waiting");
        }

    }
```

I have created TMSCore.jar and have set this example.class as entry point ,of my jar file.

Then i have created a module for this project in C:\Jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1\modules\org\tms\main , and pasted the jar in the same path

then i have created module.xml and pasted in the same path

## module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.tms">
   <resources>
    <resource-root path="TMSCore.jar"/>
   </resources>
</module>
```

then i have created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my webproject/web-inf directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.tms"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

when i start the server with my war containing above jboss-deployment-structure.xml, in my console its showing deployed TMSCore.jar

but my "waiting" text in my jar is not displayed on console

my requirement is i should get "================================> waiting" on my console once jboss is started up

or else can any one can suggest how to make a jar to execute on starting jboss server?

BTW i am using JBOSS7.1

Answer (score 2):

If I am right it's because JBoss doesn't **execute** a library, it only **loads** the classes contained in the `jar` file. So putting a main function and generating an executable `jar` will not help.

If your goal is to have an global module on the server, I suggest you these modifications:

1. Create the module (as you have already done)
2. Declare it as dependency in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` (as you have already done)
3. Declare it as global module on the server, so it will be loaded only once by JBoss. Edit the configuration file `standalone.xml` and modify the section:

   ```xml
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
       <global-modules>
           <module name="org.tms" />
       </global-modules>
   </subsystem>
   ```

Now you have a module that have classes loaded only once. I you need to have only one instance of your `Example` class, the I suggest you to use an singleton:

```java
public class Example {

    // The only one instance
    private static Example instance;

    // Private constructor to avoid creation of other instances of this class
    private Example()
    {
        System.out.println("================================> waiting");
    }


    public static Example getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Example();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Then to use it in all projects on the server

```java
Example ex = Example.getInstance();
```

will give you back the existing instance (or create one the first time).

**Notice:** I can't try, so no guarantee that that will work.

---

**Edit:** Maybe a small modification of the `Example` class can also make it run during the classes loading:

```java
public class Example {

    // The only one instance
    private static Example instance = new Example();

    // Private constructor to avoid creation of other instances of this class
    private Example()
    {
        System.out.println("================================> waiting");
    }

    public static Example getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Again: not tested.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a jar, but you can execute a startup method in a singleton.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
 public class FooBean {

   @PostConstruct 
   void atStartup() { ... }

   @PreDestroy
   void atShutdown() { ... }

}
```

This will happen at application start up and shutdown.  I'd call the function you need from there.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html